# Scaling and changing contrast of an image

Tags: python, image-processing

This is not my homework - I'm just learning to code in Python by myself. It's not easy, I don't have any coding background and I'm not that good in English (sorry if I have some mistakes).

I want to make two things in Python but I'm having difficulties with the following:

1. **I want to make a function which scales down an image.**

   I'm not sure how to write this algorithm, but I do have a solution in mind. The user will enter a value/factor/number they want to scale down by. If the user enters `2`, then all the rows and columns of the image that are multiples of 2 will be deleted and therefore the image will be smaller.

   Is this a good idea? How would I best accomplish this? I mean, how can I run on the pixels (the matrix) of an image?
2. **Change the contrast of the image by making it darker or lighter.**

   I'm not sure how to do it, but I thought it could be done in a similar way to my previous point where the user enters a number, e.g. 2, then all the values of the matrix will be doubled. If the user enters X then the values of the rows and columns will be X3 and so on.

   What do you think about this? Same problem, how can I run on each pixel in the matrix of an image? These methods will be used on multiple images each of different sizes.

Now, what I've done until now:

```
def resizing_it_down(iimm, number):
    width, height = iimm.size
    the_pix = iimm.load()
    the_out_px = Image.new('L', (width, height), 'white')
    out_pix = the_out_px.load()

    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
        if j % number == 0 and i % number == 0:
            out_pix[i,j] = in_pix[j,i]

    return the_out_px
```

I have a similar function for changing the brightness of the image.

Note: please try not to change the structure of the code or the function. I want to code this way, in the basic and simple way, even if it's not the most pythonic way...

Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Which library are you using to do load your image/do your processing?

Comment: @Michael0x2a As an aside, you should consider using Pillow instead of PIL: https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow … PIL hasn’t been actively maintained in years, in spite of its status as the go-to Python image library. Pillow is a “friendly fork” that actively and transparently builds on the solid foundation of the PIL codebase.